# Dynamically changing the height of an image won't resize parent div's width

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a vertically fluid layout that includes floating images.

When I change the height of the window the images scale correctly, however the width of the parent div does not increase/decrease with the image it contains.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cCHdU/1/) - Modify the height of the result panel to see what i'm talking about.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-640-480-7.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-640-480-7.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    bottom: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    background: blue;
}
.item {
    margin-right: 10px;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    background: red;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
.item img {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
}
```

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you've floated the item. You should be using "display:inline" instead.

When you float something, you take it out of the document flow. This prevents elements around it from reacting to it.

```
.container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    bottom: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    background: blue;
}
.item {
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    margin-right: 10px;
    background: red;
    display:inline;
}
.item img {
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    display:inline;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cCHdU/2/